# Word 2010 - Paste as Excel "Paste Link" - have table objects which are linked together

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010

I don't know if this can be done or if my one line heading is correct for my question.

I sometimes have elements such as a table that I reuse by copying it multiple times.. This cause a problem if I choose to change one thing in the table - I then have to manually update all the tables.

What I want is more like what I do in programming. Here I create a single method that I can call in different places in my code. I only need to update the declaration of the method and not all the calls.

Alternatively it would useful if it worked similar to the Excel "Paste Link"

[image]

[image]

The only difference is here that there is one Master and the copies are Slaves. That will do for me to...

It is important that you answer works for tables, thanks :D

Comment: +1 for the animated GIF! Do I understand you correctly that you're looking for a "Linked Copy" in from Word to Word, similar to the Past Link from Excel to Excel?

Comment: Yes, from Word to Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible in Microsoft Word. What you will need to do is insert a bookmark around the table you want to use as the "source" and then insert a special field which will duplicate the table in another place in the document. The field is what maintains a link to the original table so it can be automatically updated from source.

1. Highlight the table (hover over the table with your mouse and click
   the arrow icon that appears at the top left of the table).
2. Go to Insert on the ribbon and choose Bookmark.
3. Write a name for the bookmark and press Add.
4. Click the position in the doucment where you want to duplicate the
   table.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to insert an empty field into the
   document.
6. Inside the curley brackets `{ }` type the name of the bookmark you
   entered previously.
7. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> or right click in-between the brackets and choose Update
   Field to update the link
8. Repeat from step four for each copy you want to insert.

After those steps you should have a copy of the original table where you want in the document. If you change the original table and want to update the linked copies then press <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd> to select all text and <kbd>F9</kbd> to update